# Merging Nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying merge two neo4j graphs using CYPHER. The first one is the example of Countries and their Capitals. The second one is a sample example I created.

```
WITH "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jimmycrequer/7aa867900d0cf0b9588d4354f09cb286/raw/countries.json" AS url
CALL apoc.load.json(url) YIELD value AS v
MERGE (c:Country {name: v.name})
SET c.population = v.population, c.area = v.area
CREATE (capital:City {name: v.capital})
CREATE (c)<-[:IS_CAPITAL_OF]-(capital)
FOREACH (n IN v.neighbors |
  MERGE (neighbor:Country {name: n})
  MERGE (c)-[:IS_NEIGHBOR_OF]-(neighbor)
)
```

To this, I'm trying to add my graph
//Manufacturers

```
MERGE (BMW:Manufacturer {name:"BMW" , headquarters :"Germany" , employees :100306,factories:25 ,revenue:95.8 ,production:1668982 ,sales: 1688982 })
MERGE(Germany:Country)-[:MANUFACTURERS]->(BMW)
```

The Node Germany has the following properties

```
id:103, area:357022, name:Germany, population:8288000
```

When, I try to look for the final output. I see there is an empty blank node created for the relationship [:MANUFACTURERS] and a node `BMW` is created.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your second query a bit. Just because you name the node variable Germany, Neo4j doesnt know you want to match the country with the name property Germany.

And in most cases you should merge or match nodes first and only then add tje relationship between the two

```
MERGE (BMW:Manufacturer {name:"BMW" , headquarters :"Germany" , employees :100306,factories:25 ,revenue:95.8 ,production:1668982 ,sales: 1688982 })
MERGE (Germany:Country{name:'Germany})
MERGE (Germany)-[:MANUFACTURERS]->(BMW)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But, shouldn't matching the first item there be enough usually i.e. Node variable matching ?

Comment: If you run it in the same query then yes, otherwise no